# How can I hide the controllers in ListAnimate?

Tags: manipulate, animation

Consider the following expression:

```
ListAnimate[{1, 2, 3}, Paneled -> False]
```

which produces:

[image: Animation]

I can hide the panels with `Paneled -> False`. But is there an option to hide the controllers as well? I just want to export a GIF to stick into a PowerPoint slide, so I don't need any further interactivity. The [documentation for `Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) does not indicate such an option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just export data (that you put in `ListAnimate[]`) directly into gif like this:

```
data = Range[10];

Export["test.gif", data, "GIF", "DisplayDurations" -> 1, AnimationRepetitions -> Infinity]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `ListAnimate`, then use option "ControlAppearance" of `Export` to `GIF` format:

```
Export["12345.gif", ListAnimate[{1, 2, 3}, Paneled -> False], "GIF", 
"ControlAppearance" -> None]
```

[image]

You can alse specify `DefaultDuration` or `AnimationRate` for `ListAnimate`.